# I want to upload array of images with filename from React JS to express, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, express, upload

I want to upload an array of images with filenames from React JS

The array contains filename and picture

[image]

Comment: Upload it to where? What are you using for a backend? Using any middleware?

Comment: to a folder in express node.js

Comment: What is your problem, what does not work exactly? You can try to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I used Multer to upload the images